# How to pass column name along with other parameters

Tags: mysql, sql

I have below SPROC in which i am passing column name(value) along with other parameters(Place,Scenario).

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[up_GetValue] 

    @Value varchar(20), @Place varchar(10),@Scenario varchar(20), @Number varchar(10)   
AS BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    DECLARE    @SQLquery  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
    set @SQLquery =  'SELECT '  + @Value + ' from PDetail where Place = ' + @Place + ' and Scenario =  ' + @Scenario + '  and Number = ' + @Number 

    exec sp_executesql @SQLquery

END
GO
```

when executing : exec [dbo].[up_GetValue] 'Service', 'HOME', 'Agent', '123697'

i am getting the below error msg

Invalid column name 'HOME'.
Invalid column name 'Agent'.

Do i need to add any thing in the sproc??

Comment: Are those supposed to be string values for the fields, or the names of other fields you are comparing the Place, Scenario, and Number fields against? Also, not MySQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First: You tagged your question as mysql but I think your code is MSSQL.

Anyway, your problem is that you need to add quotes around each string valued parameter.

Like this:

```
alter PROCEDURE [dbo].[up_GetValue] 
    @Value varchar(20), @Place varchar(10),@Scenario varchar(20), @Number varchar(10)   
AS BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    DECLARE    @SQLquery  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
    set @SQLquery =  'SELECT '  + QUOTENAME(@Value) + ' from PDetail where Place =  ''' + @Place + ''' and Scenario =  ''' + @Scenario + '''  and Number = ''' + @Number +''''
    print @SQLquery
    exec sp_executesql @SQLquery

END
GO
```

Update:

Use `QUOTENAME` to make sure it works.

QUOTENAME:

> Returns a Unicode string with the delimiters added to make the input string a valid SQL Server delimited identifier.

Comment: You accepted my answer, did it work? or still getting incorrect syntax?

Answer (score 0):

You need to quote column names with ` (backtick) and string values with ".

```
set @SQLquery =  'SELECT `'  + @Value + '` from PDetail where Place = "' + @Place + '" and Scenario =  "' + @Scenario + '"  and Number = ' + @Number
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using a prepared statement instead of concatinating the string.

Example:

```
PREPARE stmt1 FROM 'SELECT ? from PDetail where Place = ? and Scenario = ? and Number = ?;
EXECUTE stmt1 USING @Value, @Place, @Scenario, @Number;
```